# Read excel xlsx file using simplexlsx in php

Tags: php, xlsx

I am using `simplexlsx.class.php` to read xlsx file type. It's giving problems when the file contain date field in the excel file.

**Sample output:**

In the file data:

Day             Date 
Thursday        2/2/2012
Friday              2/3/2012

**Program output:**

Day          Date

Thursday     40941
Friday           40942

It's not give the correct date

```
<?php

if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {

require_once "simplexlsx.class.php";

$xlsx = new SimpleXLSX( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] );

echo '<h1>Parsing Result</h1>';
echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="3" style="border-collapse: collapse">';

list($cols,) = $xlsx->dimension();

foreach( $xlsx->rows() as $k => $r) {
    if ($k == 0) continue; // skip first row
    echo '<tr>';
    for( $i = 0; $i < $cols; $i++)
    {

        echo '<td>'.( (isset($r[$i])) ? $r[$i] : '&nbsp;' ).'</td>';

    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
}

?>
<h1>Upload</h1>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
*.XLSX <input type="file" name="file"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Parse" />
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those are the correct dates, just in Excel's internal format: number of days since Jan 1st 1900 (allowing for 1900 being a leap year). Clearly something in the simplexlsx class is converting the xlsx date value to the Excel internal format.

I've not come across simplexlsx before (which surprises me as I thought I knew all the Excel file reader/writer libraries for PHP)... but somewhere in the code there must be a method to handle that conversion, so I'd imagine that there would also be a method for the reverse (converting Excel timestamp to PHP)

**EDIT**

The method you want is in the code:

```
function unixstamp( $excelDateTime ) {
    $d = floor( $excelDateTime ); // seconds since 1900
    $t = $excelDateTime - $d;
    return ($d > 0) ? ( $d - 25569 ) * 86400 + $t * 86400 : $t * 86400;
}
```

I make no guarantees that it's accurate

**EDIT FURTHER**

```
function unixstamp( $excelDateTime ) {
    $d = floor( $excelDateTime ); // seconds since 1900
    $t = $excelDateTime - $d;
    return ($d > 0) ? ( $d - 25569 ) * 86400 + $t * 86400 : $t * 86400;
}


$dateVal = 40941;
$unixDateVal = unixstamp($dateVal);
var_dump($unixDateVal);
echo date('d-M-Y',$unixDateVal);
```

gives

```
float 1328140800
```

which looks remarkably like a unix timestamp value in the correct range for this year, and sure enough:

```
02-Feb-2012
```

So looks like it works to me

Comment: Not working..i send the date field to unixstamp function it's not returning the actual date.

Comment: Just wanted to mention after finding this years later. The value might be a float which represents a date time value, for example 43540.101599456. This shows up as "3/16/2019 2:26 AM" when you open this in excel. Using date() with this method might give you a different answer, because that will attempt to format in local time (which Excel apparently doesn't do). You can solve this by using `gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s',$unixDateVal);` to get a value that matches Excel.

Comment: @khartnett - 43540.101599456 would be an MS Excel SErialized timestamp, which is not the same as a Unix timestamp... Functions like `date()` and `gmdate()` work with Unix timestamps. It has nothing whatsoever to do with local times, and everything to do with the fact that they are completely different types of values, counting different time intervals, with completely different base points

Comment: @MarkBaker are you saying that the MS Excel Serialized timestamp is different than the $excelDateTime in your answer? Using your calculation in your answer, I was able to get the correct value when accounting for time (matches when opened in Excel) down to the minute. So they surely seem related

Comment: To clarify, I'm not saying 43540.101599456 is a unix timestamp, it's still the number of days since Jan 1st 1900. It appears this format doesn't have a specific time zone, but converting it to a unix timestamp using your calculation will make it relative to the UTC time zone, and using gmdate will convert it correctly.